# How to show event without duplication in full calendar year view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I tried fullcalendar year view by refering below.

http://embed.plnkr.co/xhahIV/

I can see yearly calendar like this. but I wonder some event is shown in duplicated style. for example event in March 1st is duplicated.

I would like to know the way to eliminate the day which belongs to next months.

If someone has idea,please let me know.

Thanks

```
// Code goes here
$(document).ready(function() {

  // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'year,month,basicWeek,basicDay'

    },
    timezone: 'local',
    height: "auto",
    selectable: true,
    dragabble: true,
    defaultView: 'year',
    yearColumns: 6,
    contentHeight: 600,

    durationEditable: true,
    bootstrap: false,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,

    events: [{
      title: "Some event",
      start: new Date('2017-1-10'),
      end: new Date('2017-1-20'),
      id: 1,
      allDay: true,
      editable: true,
      eventDurationEditable: true,
    }, ],
    select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      var title = prompt('Event Title:',"hospitalization");
      if (title) {
        var event = {
          title: title,
          start: start.clone(),
          end: end.clone(),
          allDay: true,
          editable: true,
          eventDurationEditable: true,
          eventStartEditable: true,
          color: 'aqua',
        };


        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
      }
    },
  })
});
```

I tried `showNonCurrentDates`options,and result is like below.it seems this option is only applied to january..

[image]

Comment: I don't know anything about this custom year view specifically, but from the screenshot it looks like it's probably achieved by rendering multiple "month" views to the screen simultaneously. If that's the case, then I would guess that maybe setting [showNonCurrentDates](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/showNonCurrentDates) to `false` might remove the problem, because that causes the month view not to render dates which are not part of that specific month. But that's just something to try, I can't guarantee it works since I don't know the implementation of that "year" view.

Comment: Isn't showing the March event in the Feb calendar a feature you want to keep? Otherwise, as ADyson says, perhaps what you want is only the days of the month show and hide the days of each month's previous and subsequent months?

Comment: I tried and updated my question,this option may seems to be applied only in january..I refered to this link. Thanks  http://embed.plnkr.co/xhahIV/